# Javascript: how is 'new Array(4)' different from Array.apply(null, {length: 4})?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to generate an empty array of a given length and the populate it with some numbers.  One way to generate an array with four sequential numerical elements is :

```
var x = Array.apply(null, {length: 4}).map(function(item, index){return index;})
```

But when I saw `Array.apply(null, {length: 4})` I thought I could instead replace it with `new Array(4)` but that is not the case.  Doing a quick test yields the following:

```
>> console.log((new Array(4)))
<< [ <4 empty items> ]

>> console.log(Array.apply(null, {length: 4}))
<< [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

Which means I can `.map` the latter but not the former.

What is the difference then between `new Array` and `Array.apply(null, {})` which I thought were both creating an array object with given length?

Comment: this seems very inefficient as it creates a new array.

Comment: What's the question? The results of the operations should make it obvious what the differences are. Are you asking for references to the specifications?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`apply` takes a context as the first parameter and an arraylike list of arguments as a second. Then it calls the function (`Array`) with the iterable as arguments.

```
Array.apply(null, [1, 2])
// Same as
Array(1, 2)
// Or
[1, 2]
```

Now if you pass an object as an arraylike, it will still iterate it like this:

```
function apply(context, args) {
  for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) { 
    /*...*/ args[i];
  }
}
```

So if you pass `{ length: 4 }` it will iterate four times and take `undefined` as an argument, so it results in something like:

```
Array.apply(null, { length: 4 })
// Same as
Array(undefined, undefined, undefined)
```

Therefore the arrays slots are not empty, but they are undefined, and as `map` only skips empty slots it will go over every entry of the second array.

By the way, the same can be achieved a bit more readable:

```
Array.from({length: 4 }, (_, i) => i)
// [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer requires a bit of drilling down into the mechanics of `Array` objects.

`new Array(4)` creates an array with length 4 but no items (Sparse Array)

`Array.apply(null, {length: 4})` creates an array with 4 undefined elements.

The second one uses a few tricks:

1. `apply` calls a function with given context and arguments provided in an array.
2. `Array`, when called directly as a function creates an array from the elements it got as arguments, e.g:

   `\> Array(1,2,3)
   [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    \> Array(...[1,2,3])
   [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    \> Array(...new Array(4))
   [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]`

So why is `Array.apply(null, {length: 4})` equivalent to `Array.apply(null, new Array(4)`?

`apply` parses the arguments array by looking at the length and then taking the relevant arguments. `{length: 4}.length` is 4, so it takes

```
{length:4}[0]
{length:4}[1]
{length:4}[2]
{length:4}[3]
```

which are all `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that
`new Array(4)` does not initialize the slots in the array.  It only sets the length property of the array. Where as `Array.apply(null, {length: 4})` initializes each slot to undefined.